# partial derivative of logit function

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

Could someone please be so kind and tell me the first partial derivative with respect to X1 for this logit function?

$$ Y(X1, X2, X3) = \frac{P1}{1 + e^{-(P2 + P3 * X1 + P4 * X2 + P5 * X3)}} $$

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's $P1 \cdot P3 \cdot e^{P2+P3\cdot X1 + P4 \cdot X2 + P5 \cdot X3}$.

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? Just learnt about this: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=differentiate+p1%2F(1%2Bexp(-p2+-p3*x1-p4*x2-p5*x3)))++with+respect+to+x1 which gives me a different result

Comment: I answered the question before you edited it. With the $1+$ added in, my answer is no longer correct.

Comment: Oop sorry did I add this afterwards - apologies!!!